# Setting time zones with site-based Group Policy

Tags: windows, windows-registry, group-policy

Setting up a Group policy to configure Time Zones based on site location.

Comment: Look into the tzutil utility in Windows.

Comment: I have read that this is not possible but if someone has an answer I would be very interested

Comment: @tyelford It's totally possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the template host to the desired time zone, then export to a .REG .

[image]

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
"Bias"=dword:0000012c
"DaylightBias"=dword:ffffffc4
"DaylightName"="@tzres.dll,-111"
"DaylightStart"=hex:00,00,03,00,02,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled"=dword:00000000
"StandardBias"=dword:00000000
"StandardName"="@tzres.dll,-112"
"StandardStart"=hex:00,00,0b,00,01,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"TimeZoneKeyName"="Eastern Standard Time"
"ActiveTimeBias"=dword:0000012c
```

Convert the [.REG to .XML](http://www.runecasters.com.au/reg2gpp)

-Note:Do not use "Replace" use "update" otherwise when the host does not match a site it will default to the UTC Timezone.

[.xml GPP file](https://paste.ee/r/qt8mV)

Then Pasted the xml into the GPP editor
[image]
[image]

Setup "Item-level targting" on the properties for each time zone
[image]
After the policy applies "Some Settings are managed by your organization" will now appear on your time zone settings.
[image: After a GPupdate /force the setting are being applied to the host]

Comment: This nearly worked for me, I had to paste the xml file into user configuration instead of computer configuration. I could also do something similar to set 24 hour time, and the date to dd.mm.yyyy

Thanks!

Comment: On Windows 10, when this registry takes effect, the clock on the taskbar does not update.